# access property of controller from within view

Tags: ember.js

I wanna do something like a progress bar, which will be controlled by ember. So in my eyes, there are two and a half ways to achieve this:

1. Have an observer in the **controller**, which sets the elements' `width` when triggered. Problem: AFAIK, one can't access DOM-elements from within the controller, i.e. like the way you'd do it in the view `this.$('#progress')`.
2. Have an observer in the **view**, which observes the controller's property. Problem: I don't know, how to observe (and access) a controller's property.
3. *(bind the controller's property via `{{bindAttr}}` to a freaky `data-progress="42"` attribute and adjust the elements `width` whenever the attribute's value has changed)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Option 2 is your best bet.

> Problem: I don't know, how to observe (and access) a controller's property.

Ember will set a view's controller property when the view is created, you can use that to access the controller's property.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  percentComplete: '0'
});

App.ProgressView = Ember.View.extend({
  percentChanged: function() {
    percentString = (this.get('controller.percentComplete') + "%");
    this.$('.bar').css('width', percentString);
  }.observes('controller.percentComplete').on('didInsertElement')
});
```

I've posted a working example here: http://jsbin.com/hitacomu/1/edit

Comment: A controller is a view??

Comment: I 2nd @Connor's comment. I am very confused by how ember seems to care more about the name, moreso than the type, of objects for hooking up its magic. Also, the jsbin link does not appear to be doing anything at the moment.

Comment: @PatrickM sorry that was a typo, should have been `App.ProgressController = Ember.Controller.extend`. Also the jsfiddle broke cause it referenced js libraries that have moved. I have updated both fiddle and my answer, hope the new version is more helpful.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the attention! But what I really want to know is why it still worked when you had the controller as an `Ember.View`.

Comment: That's a good question, basically it still worked because this is such a simple example. You are right that Ember doesn't care about the type of object you give it, just expects that the object has the right capabilities. Usually it makes sense to extend Ember.Controller but you don't have to. In this simple example we don't do many 'controller' things (like sending actions) so any of Ember.View, Ember.Object or Ember.Controller would have worked. But as soon as we tried doing something like `{{action submit}}` the Ember.View and Ember.Object versions would break.